# How can I plot a discontinuous function without a connecting line?

Tags: python, tkinter, math

I am using Tkinter in Python to develop a graphing calculator and I'm having some trouble with discontinuous functions. Here is my code for drawing a line from the equation tan(x) on a graph of dimensions 640x640:

```
for i in range(0, 640):
    x = (i - 320)/32
    try:
        y = math.tan(x)
        y = 320 - (32 * y)
        if i == 0:
            prevx = x
            prevy = y
        graph.create_line(prevx, prevy, i, y, fill='#ff0000', width=3)
        prevx = i
        prevy = y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

When I run this code [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIlkG.png) is the graph I get. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation I have devised a solution. Here is the new code:

```
prevx = 0
prevy = 0
error = False
for i in range(0, 640):
    x = (i - 320)/32
    try:
        y = math.tan(x)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        error = True
    except ValueError:
        error = True
    else:
        y = 320 - (32 * y)
        if i == 0:
            prevx = x
            prevy = y
        if error == False:
            graph.create_line(prevx, prevy, i, y, fill='#ff0000', width=3)
        else:
            graph.create_line(prevx, prevy, i, y, fill='#ff0000', width=3, state='hidden')
            error = False
        prevx = i
        prevy = y
```

I created a new boolean variable `error` to hide the line being drawn when a math error is returned. Note that this solution works for pretty much every discontinuous function including: y=1/x, y=sqrt(x) and y=log(x). However, it doesn't work for y=tan(x) as for some reason in the Python `math` library tan(90) doesn't produce an error (same goes for sec and cosec). I'd appreciate if anyone could figure out a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code.  If you want to hide the vertical line, you might try out the following code.

```
import math
import tkinter

tangent = tkinter.Tk()

graph = tkinter.Canvas(tangent, width = 820, height = 800)
graph.pack()

graph.create_window(1000, 600)

for i in range(0, 940):
    x = (i - 320)/32
    
    try:
        y = math.tan(x)
        y = 320 - (32 * y) 
        if i == 0:
            prevx = x
            prevy = y
        if (y > prevy):
            graph.create_line(0, 0, 0, 0, fill='#ff0000', width=0)  # Effectively hiding the line when going from infinity to negative infinity
        else:
            graph.create_line(prevx, prevy, i, y, fill='#ff0000', width=3)
        prevx = i
        prevy = y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
        
tangent.mainloop()
```

I did not have the parameters you used to define your graph so I just defined a rudimentary tkinter graph.

It makes the vertical line invisible by effectively stating:

- set the line coordinates to (0,0,0,0) when the value of "y" is larger than the previous value of "y".

Experimenting with the output, that condition seemed to come into play when the value of "y" exceeded a value of 800.  If you test this out, you might derive a different answer.

This resulted in a rudimentary graph as noted in the following image.

[image: Tangent Graph]

Test this out and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: I've tested you're solution and it does the work for the line y = tan(x) so thanks for that. However this solution is not very versatile as it doesn't work for most other functions; y = -tan(x) for instance. Making the graph still plot the line where it shouldn't be but with a width of 0 is a great idea though.

Comment: Good.  I hope that allows you to progress.